# Submit data to database only when validation is passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have tried alot to research this on different websites, however couldn't get it done may be because I am new to programming. This is my code. It sends the data and then asks for validation instead it should clear validation and then send data to database. Need assistance

```
var createAllErrors = function() {
        var form = $( this ),
            errorList = $( "ul.errorMessages", form );

        var showAllErrorMessages = function() {
            errorList.empty();

            // Find all invalid fields within the form.
            var invalidFields = form.find( ":invalid" ).each( function( index, node ) {

                // Find the field's corresponding label
                var label = $( "label[for=" + node.id + "] "),
                    // Opera incorrectly does not fill the validationMessage property.
                    message = node.validationMessage || 'Invalid value.';

                errorList
                    .show()
                    .append( "<li><span>" + label.html() + "</span> " + message + "</li>" );
            });
        };
    // Support Safari
        form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
            if ( this.checkValidity && !this.checkValidity() ) {
                $( this ).find( ":invalid" ).first().focus();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        $( "input[type=submit], button:not([type=button])", form )
            .on( "click", showAllErrorMessages);

        $( "input", form ).on( "keypress", function( event ) {
            var type = $( this ).attr( "type" );
            if ( /date|email|month|number|search|tel|text|time|url|week/.test ( type )
              && event.keyCode == 13 ) {
                showAllErrorMessages();
            }
        });
    };

$( "form" ).each( createAllErrors );

$('.submit-btn').click(function(){

    var data = $('.form-horizontal :Input').serializeArray();
    //now the data is sent to server database using .post(sent url, data to be sent, result when successfully sent data)
    $.post($('.form-horizontal').attr('action'), data, function(info){$('#result').html(info); });

    clearInput();
    });

$('.form-horizontal').submit( function(){
    return false;
});

function clearInput () {
    $('.form-horizontal :Input').each( function(){
        $(this).val('') ;
    });
};
```

Comment: A jsfiddle example would be very useful

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5phvvgo6/

Comment: Your form has a post action, this will fire before you js has a chance to validate. You will need to defer your form post until after validation or remove the form post and just post from js

Comment: easiest way to probably do this is change your submit button to not include the type=submit  `<button name="submit" class="submit-btn" >Submit</button>` then after doing your validation submit the form with `$('form.form-horizontal').submit()`

Comment: there's tons of examples on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809295/javascript-form-submission-after-validation

Comment: The form has action UserInfor.php. It runs as soon as the submit button is clicked without checking for validation. You are right there are lots of examples on stackoverflow and I tried many of them with no success. May be this is because I am new and making some mistake that I couldn't get